# How to fillter a CSV file with csvgrep and print only certain columns?

Tags: csvkit

Is it possible in a single invocation, or do I need to reparse the lines with a pipe?

E.g. given:

test.csv

```
ok,1
ok,2
ko,3
```

and what I want is only the second column if the first column is `ok`, i.e. the desired output is:

```
1
2
```

The only way I know how to do it is with a pipe into `csvcut`:

```
csvgrep -H -c1 -mok test.csv | csvcut -c2 | tail -n+2
```

This example from the documentation: https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/2_examining_the_data.html#csvgrep-find-the-data-you-need does something similar, so maybe it is the only way?

```
csvcut -c county,item_name,total_cost data.csv | csvgrep -c county -m LANCASTER | csvlook
```

Comment: csvkit works in this way. There are other tools that do this in one command, but you probably don't care about them.

Comment: @aborruso thanks. Any good compiled tools that might go faster BTW? I'm going to try https://github.com/DavyLandman/csvtools a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.9.0/installing-miller/) you can run

```
mlr --csv -N filter '$1=="ok"' then cut -f 2 input.csv
```

to get

```
1
2
```

As input I have used

```
ok,1
ok,2
ko,3
```